# How to treat open data analysis questions

Tags: discussion, tags

Sometimes questions are asked, which can be roughly described as:

**A:** I have an unsorted heap of data (so it is sometimes more, sometimes less required to create predictors)

**B:** I have a target/response - variable (to create or already available) or a vague idea where I want to get

Resulting question: How do I get from A to B ?

Examples:

- [Logistic Regression and Dataset Structure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6653/logistic-regression-and-dataset-structure)
- [How should I deal with features with time related values in Bayesian network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6777/how-should-i-deal-with-features-with-time-related-values-in-bayesian-network/) (which btw should be deleted anytime soon ... the discussion is leading nowhere)
- [Failure detection method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6783/failure-detection-method)
- [General approaches to model car traffic in a parking garage](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7166/general-approaches-to-model-car-traffic-in-a-parking-garage)
- [Resources for beginners - how to determine probability of user action based on certain criteria?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7179/resources-for-beginners-how-to-determine-probability-of-user-action-based-on-ce)

I hope you get the point. From my experience on the rapidminer-forum, those questions are invitations for discussions and do not have something like a "correct", but maybe a best answer. As far as I see, answers can only be suggestions to try this or that. Don't get me wrong: I really like this type of questions, because they link practical problems with algorithms/formulas.

My questions:

- Are those questions generally (or in most cases) cw ?
- How to tag those questions (data-mining seems to be too broad) ?

**EDIT:**
I added two more examples. Additionally, if no one cares to a) either a agree to my proposal or b) deny it and make another one, nothing will be changed. I am just not self-confident enough to accept my proposal and retag all questions of that kind. As far as I understand statsexchange, tags should be discussed instead of created spontaneously.

Comment: Very good question! But I just want to point that the 2nd thread you linked to was poorly worded, IMO; and about the third one, the OP didn't answer the clarifications that were asked -- so what can we do?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposal:

1. Because a) it is sometimes hard to tell whether such a question is cw or not  and b) to encourage more answers (yay, reputation), such questions generally should not be cw.
2. Use the already existing tag "modeling" for such questions